# Are these interchangeable? Do they mean the same thing?

Tags: word-usage

Are these interchangeable? Do they mean the same thing ?

You can depend on Jane – she always keeps her promises.
You can count on Jane – she always keeps her promises.
You can rely on Jane – she always keeps her promises.

(Feel free to correct any of my sentences, because a want to learn a lot from my mistakes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think those three phrases are synonymous, certainly so in that context, where the last clause makes it clear that the question is whether her promises will be kept. You could separate all three examples into two separate sentences, or you could separate the clauses with a semicolon. The dash has an informal feel to it.